# How to make animation using JLabel in Java/Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I have a final project of a Java course, it is Frog jump game. Here is the video to describe it :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NxWWP9cK24o

I don't know how to use Timer, I only know Thread.sleep. But it's not working.

Here my code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;




/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author gamekvnn
 */
public class FrogGame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    /**
     * Creates new form ba
     */

    public FrogGame() {
        initComponents();
    }
        Timer time;
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        frog1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        frog2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        frog3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        fr0g2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        fr0g1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        fr0g3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        background = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setLayout(null);

        frog1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("/home/gamekvnn/NetBeansProjects/Project/src/frog1.png")); // NOI18N
        jPanel1.add(frog1);
        frog1.setBounds(10, 310, 80, 80);

        frog2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("/home/gamekvnn/NetBeansProjects/Project/src/frog1.png")); // NOI18N
        jPanel1.add(frog2);
        frog2.setBounds(110, 310, 80, 80);

        frog3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("/home/gamekvnn/NetBeansProjects/Project/src/frog1.png")); // NOI18N
        jPanel1.add(frog3);
        frog3.setBounds(210, 310, 80, 80);

        fr0g2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("/home/gamekvnn/NetBeansProjects/Project/src/frog2.png")); // NOI18N
        jPanel1.add(fr0g2);
        fr0g2.setBounds(510, 310, 80, 80);

        fr0g1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("/home/gamekvnn/NetBeansProjects/Project/src/frog2.png")); // NOI18N
        jPanel1.add(fr0g1);
        fr0g1.setBounds(610, 310, 80, 80);

        fr0g3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("/home/gamekvnn/NetBeansProjects/Project/src/frog2.png")); // NOI18N
        jPanel1.add(fr0g3);
        fr0g3.setBounds(410, 310, 80, 80);

        jButton1.setText("Start");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(jButton1);
        jButton1.setBounds(520, 20, 100, 29);

        background.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("/home/gamekvnn/NetBeansProjects/Project/src/UZKEjzG.png")); // NOI18N
        jPanel1.add(background);
        background.setBounds(0, 0, 710, 440);
        background.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("background");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 708, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 442, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        frog3.setLocation(frog3.getX()+100, frog3.getY());
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);;                 //1000 milliseconds is one second.
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        fr0g3.setLocation(fr0g3.getX()-200, fr0g3.getY());
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);;
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        fr0g2.setLocation(fr0g2.getX()-100, fr0g2.getY());
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);;
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        frog3.setLocation(frog3.getX()+200, frog3.getY());
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);;
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        frog2.setLocation(frog2.getX()+200, frog2.getY());
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);;
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        frog1.setLocation(frog1.getX()+100, frog1.getY());
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);;
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        fr0g3.setLocation(fr0g3.getX()-200, fr0g3.getY());
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);;
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        fr0g2.setLocation(fr0g2.getX()-200, fr0g2.getY());
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);;
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        fr0g1.setLocation(fr0g1.getX()-200, fr0g1.getY());
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);;
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        frog3.setLocation(frog3.getX()+100, frog3.getY());
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);;
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        frog2.setLocation(frog2.getX()+200, frog2.getY());
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);;
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        frog1.setLocation(frog1.getX()+200, frog1.getY());
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);;
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        fr0g2.setLocation(fr0g2.getX()-100, fr0g2.getY());
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);;
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        fr0g1.setLocation(fr0g1.getX()-200, frog1.getY());
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);;
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        frog1.setLocation(frog1.getX()+100, frog1.getY());
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);;
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrogGame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrogGame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrogGame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrogGame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new FrogGame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel background;
    private javax.swing.JLabel fr0g1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel fr0g2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel fr0g3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel frog1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel frog2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel frog3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: (1-) `but i dont know how to use Timer` - well search the forum or web for examples. Don't expect us to read your code to try to understand what you are doing. We are not going to rewrite the code for you. You can also read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Swing Timers]() for information and examples.`Tonight is my deadline` - that is irrelevant to the question. You need to plan your time better.

Answer (score 1):

> , i only know Thread.sleep

Well that won't work because the code is executing on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)` which is the Thread that repaints the GUI. So if you keep telling it to sleep in never gets a chance to repaint itself.

So if you want to use Thread.sleep, you need to start a separate Thread.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information. Maybe you could also use a SwingWorker as discussed in the tutorial for the worker Thread.